# Logic Regression Equation without Global Minimiser

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I've got an assignment for uni that goes as follows:

> Let $y \in \{-1,1\}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$ be the data matrix with rows $x_i^T, i=1, \cdots, m$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ denote the objective function of the logistic regression function,
> $$f(w) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}h(y_i\langle w, x_i\rangle),$$
> where $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $h(t)=\log(1+e^{-t})$. Given that:
>
> - $h$ is convex and decreases strictly monotonically to 0
> - $f$ is convex
> - $\nabla f(w) = X^T p(w)$ where
>   $p(w)_i = -y_i \frac{1}{1+\exp(y_i\langle w, x_i\rangle)}$
> - $f$ is $\beta$-smooth for $\beta = \frac{1}{4}\sigma_{max}(X^T)\sigma_{max}(X)\big(=\frac{1}{4}\sigma_{max}(X)^2\big)$, where $\sigma_{max}$ denotes the largest singular value
> - the dataset is linearly separable by a hyperplane passing through the origin: there is some $w^*$ so that $y_i\langle w, x_i\rangle > 0$ for $i = 1, \cdots, m$
>
> **Show that $f$ does not have a global minimiser.**

There is a hint given that one should consider $\langle w^*, \nabla f(w)\rangle$, but i have no idea how this would help me. All previous exercises in this assignment went quite well, but with this exercise I just have no idea where to start. Do any of you know how I could start at tackling this exercise. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\langle w, \nabla f(w) \rangle = -\sum_{i = 1}^m  \frac{y_i \langle w,x_i \rangle }{1+\exp(y_i \langle w^\top x_i \rangle)}. $$
From the above, it is easy to see that $\langle w^*, \nabla f(w^*) \rangle < 0$. This means that, at the point $w^*$, $w^*$ itself is a decreasing direction for $f$. Moreover, for any $\alpha >0$, we find that also
$$\langle \alpha w^*, \nabla f( \alpha w^*) \rangle < 0. $$
I'll leave the verification of this to you. By the above inequality, $f$ will forever decrease in the direction $w^*$, and thus, it does not have a global minimum.

Comment: dont you mean $\langle w, \nabla f(w)\rangle = \ldots$?

Comment: Oops! You're right. I have corrected it.

Comment: No problem! thanks for your help!